# Аутентификация Facebook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Требуется залогиниться в facebook и сделать пост на стену (от имени залогиненного пользователя).
Существует некая программа, с которой могут (по требованию) передаваться такие параметры:

Логин пользователя *Facebook*;
Пароль пользователя *Facebook*.

Насколько я понял, для того, чтобы осуществить логин, нужно написать скрипт (*C#*), который будет выполнять вход, а для этого нужно:

1. Создать приложение в *Facebook* (сделано).
2. Создать группу в *Facebook* (сделано).
3. Получить *access_token* средствами *AppID* и *App Secret* (реализовано).
4. Отобразить пользователю окно, в котором он должен войти в свой аккаунт (*OAuth*).

И здесь начинается самое интересное. Программа, с которой передаются параметры, не может выводить окна, она может лишь только передать из себя логин и пароль (в скрипт, который мне нужен). Вот такая проблема.

Нашел лишь только реализации средствами *WinFowrms*, а для данной задачи это недопустимо.

Можно ли произвести логин без окна *WinForms*, используя *access_token* (удалось получить), логин и пароль аккаунта?

Код *C#* который был написан, в качестве тестового:

```
class Program
{
    private const string FacebookApiId = "********************";
    private const string FacebookApiSecret = "*************************";

    private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookApiId, FacebookApiSecret);

        PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
    }

    static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty;
        string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

            accessToken = query["access_token"];
        }

        if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");

        return accessToken;
    }

    static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
            messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
            //messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
            //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
            //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
            //messagePost.caption = "my caption"; 
            messagePost.message = message;
        //messagePost.description = "my description";

        var result = facebookClient.Post("/ACCOUNT_ID/feed", messagePost);
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: А как именно используется WinForms? Есть хороший шанс, что можно легко вычленить из этого кода модельную часть.

Comment: @VladD, в том то и дело, что в приложении,нужно будет произвести вход в Facebook и осуществить пост на стену.Ни о каких виндовс формах и речи идти не может.Условия таковы: приложение,в котором можно написать абсолютно любого рода код(С#),которое будет выполнять логин,и постить запись на стену,но без винформ.

Comment: @VladD , возможно ли это?

Comment: Ну, это зависит от того, что именно делает код на WinForms. Если он хостит браузер и работает через него, тут сложнее, поскольку вам придётся эмулировать браузер, чтобы сделать то же самое. Но если код использует WinForms только для ввода логина/пароля, то всю графическую часть можно выкинуть, и оставить лишь суть.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь использовать Selenium Web Driver -- тулзовина для взаимодействия с браузерами, которая используется для автоматического тестирования веб-приложений. Если нужно видимЬІй браузер -- используешь хром или фаярфокс. Если невидимЬІй -- phantomJs.

Там довольно просто сделать то что тебе нужно.

---

Если же способ не подходит, то можно воспользоватся FaceBook API. Уверен, там есть доступный функционал для этого.